# Given two tangents $\varepsilon_{1},\varepsilon_{2}$ of the curve $c_{1}$, on two specific points $x_1, x_2$, find the tangents

Tags: calculus, plane-curves

> Let $\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2$ be the equations of the tangents to the curve $c: y = 1+x^2$, on the points $x_1 = 2$ and $x_2 = -2$, respectively. Prove that the equations for the two tangents are $\varepsilon_1: y = 4x -3$ and $\varepsilon_2: y = -4x-3\;$.

Unfortunately, I have no *hunch* or *idea* on how to begin on this. We've got the two points but how would I go about proving that the given tangent equations are the correct ones?

Source: a sheet of the class's 2012 final exams, I'm slowly trying to solve the exercises in it or find the general layout. I would like to ask for any help or methodologies that will make it easier for me to solve.

Comment: Just to have an idea... Do you have some knowledge about function derivatives and analytic geometry (i.e. a line that pass through a given point and with a given slope)?

Comment: @the_candyman Yes, don't worry about having to explain the bare basics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function can be interpreted geometrically as the slope of the tangent to the function.

The derivative of $1+x^2$ is $2x$, so substituting the given values for $x_1$ and $x_2$ we obtain that the slope of the tangent line in those points is $4$ and $-4$.

Now you should recall from analytic geometry that the formula for a line passing through the point $(x_0,y_0)$ with slope $m$ is $y-y_0=m(x-x_0)$

For example the line passing through $(2,5)$ (the point with x-coordinate equal to $2$ in your curve) and having slope $m=4$ is given by $y-5=4(x-2)$ that is $y=4x-3$

A similar calculation will show that also the other tangent is correct

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and explanation, first of all. But would you mind elaborating, a bit, on how you ended up on the point (2,5) and what exactly you proved by ending up at $y=4x-3$?

Comment: Nevermind, I think I got it. You came up with a point that would lead to proving that $y=4x-3$ is indeed a tangent at that location, where $x=2$. I would appreciate a tip on how you magically "picked" $(2,5)$, though :-)     Was it a hunch or did you follow methodology?

Comment: We know that $x=2$ because the excercise gives this information, to know the other coordinate of the point belonging to the curve with $x$-coordinate=$2$ just substitute $x=2$ in the equation of the curve: $c(2)=1+2^2$.

Comment: For the second point you have to substitute $x=-2$ in the equation of the curve (you'll find that the second point is $(-2,5)$, since this curve is a parabola symmetric with respect to the y-axis)

Comment: Ι understand now. Sorry for the stupid comment-question.